# Return multiple records, but it should limit 1 record per each similar condition

Tags: mysql, sql

```sql
+----+--------------------+
| id | name  |      age   |      
+----+--------------------+
|  1 | James  |        20 |
|  2 | Ruth   |        20 |
|  3 | Blue   |        15 |
|  4 | Redd   |        15 |
|  5 | Arkk   |        30 |
|  6 | Arthur |        30 |
```

**Expected results:**

```
+----+--------------------+
| id | name  |      age   |      
+----+--------------------+
|  1 | James  |        20 |
|  3 | Blue   |        15 |
|  6 | Arthur |        30 |
```

**Explanation:**
In the results, **James** is representing all people aged `20`. And **Blue** is representing all people aged `15`. And so on..

**Question:**
How can this query type of query be achieved? Thank you.

Comment: Where did "Jack" come from?  And nothing is **Blue**.

Comment: @GordonLinoff it was typo

Comment: So's Arthur (or possibly Athur)

Comment: @Maskide . . . Edit the question and fix the question.

Comment: *In the results, James is representing all people aged 20.* Why not Ruth? What is the criteria?

Comment: @Akina what u mean? Randomly picked those

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want one name per age, you can use:

```
select max(name), age
from t
group by age;
```

If you want the first *row*, then:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.id = (select min(t2.id) from t t2 where t2.age = t.age);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Row_number.

```
WITH cte1 AS
(SELECT id, name, age, row_number() over(partition by age order by id) rn
FROM table1)
SELECT id, name, age FROM cte1 WHERE rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Microsoft SQL Server:

```
SELECT TOP 1 id, name, age
ORDER BY id
GROUP BY age
FROM table
```